# can't login to docker using command prompt in windows 10

Tags: docker, web-scraping, scrapy-splash

earlier I was trying to install splash using docker but it was displaying the issue

```
C:\Users\krishan>docker pull scrapinghub/splash
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Head https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/scrapinghub/splash/manifests/latest: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

so I tried this but still facing issues

---

```
C:\Users\krishan>docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: krishaner
Password:
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

please help!!

Comment: All issue solved

Answer (score 0):

> I was getting this same error in Windows 10 Home using Docker Toolbox. Changing my DNS to Google's 8.8.8.8 (secondary to 8.8.4.4) also worked for me (per @aasaanhai here). Detailed instructions for how to do so here (see section II).

REF: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/611

solved my issue as I have already set my docker DNS server 8.8.8.8